# list one record autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using the Jquery autocomplete, when I type the first three letters I get the full list of all managers, when I should only get one. I have the following code from my project controller

```
def project_list  
    list=Project.all.map{|i|i.manager_user_id}
    arr= [].concat(list.sort{|a,b| a[0]<=>b[0]}).to_json
    render :json =>arr
  end
```

Is there something I've done wrong.

[image: Example]

Application.js

```
 function log(message) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo("#log");
    }

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/managerlist",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var results = [];
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    var itemToAdd = {
                        value: item,
                        label: item
                    };
                    results.push(itemToAdd);
                });
                return response(results);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

In the picture above I typed in 'Arm' I should only be shown 'Deshawn Armstrong' but instead I am being shown the full list

Edited:

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :project_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :project_name %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :manager_user_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :manager_user_id, :id => "term"%>

</p>
```

Above is mangerlist page that contains a form. From what you explained to me, I'm thinking that you have to put the var 'term' on the page like I have done above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you filtering you results by `request.term`? If you are not, then the whole list of managers is returning as the matching string.

Request.term should be sent to your `url: "/managerlist"` and that should return results filtered by the term.

So, your url will look like this when sent by ajax: `/managerlist?term=arm`. Take the request var `term` and filter your list by it. That will have to be done on the `managerlist` page that is written in ruby (I believe).

Actually, what I'm saying is the `list` in your ruby page must return data filtered by the `term` value:

```
def manager_list 
list=Project.all.map{|i|i.manager_user_id} 
arr= [].concat(list.sort{|a,b| a[0]<=>b[0]}).to_json 
render :json =>arr
end
```

`list` should only contain values filtered by `term`

Comment: I am using request.term. I have placed it after maxRows. That's right isn't it?

Comment: @Djj `request.term` is sent to your `url: "/managerlist"` as  a url parameter. You sort filter the records that you send back to the autocomplete with it on your `/managerlist` page. Right now it is doing nothing.

Comment: How do I go about doing this as I am fairly new to javascript. I did the the autocomplete from the jquery Ui website and adapted it. This is the only part that I find confusing.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I believe that what your saying is take the var term and put it on my manager list page so that when the page is rendered it calls the var 'term'? I've updated my post to show what I think you mean

Comment: @Djj I'm not too familiar with ruby so I tried to explain again in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, you've helped me greatly really appreciate it.